# define schemaLocation in Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I want to generate this xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ru:myobject XML_DATA="2.1.0"
    xmlns:ru="http://www.aaa.com" xmlns:t="http://www.bbb.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.aaa.com aaa.xsd
http://www.bbb.com bbb.xsd
http://www.ccc.com ddd.xsd">
```

The problem is the namespace in `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute.

here is my code:

```
XNamespace mynamespace = "http://www.aaa.com/test/";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.aaa.com/test/ aaa.xsd http://www.bbb.com bbb.xsd http://www.ccc.com ccc.xsd";
XElement myobject = new XElement(mynamespace + "myobject", new XAttribute("XML_DATA", "2.1.0"));
myobject.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ru", "http://www.aaa.com"));
myobject.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "t", "http://www.bbb.com"));
myobject.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));

myobject.Add(new XAttribute(xsi+"schemaLocation", xsi.ToString()));
```

It generates this header and I don't know why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ru:myobject XML_DATA="2.1.0"
xmlns:ru="http://www.aaa.com" xmlns:t="http://www.bbb.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
p3:schemaLocation=" http://www.aaa.com aaa.xsd http://www.bbb.com bbb.xsd http://www.ccc.com ddd.xsd"
xmlns:p3="http://www.aaa.com aaa.xsd http://www.bbb.com bbb.xsd http://www.ccc.com ddd.xsd">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the following code online:

```
XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
XNamespace defaultNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://www.foo.bar");

XElement doc = new XElement(
   new XElement(defaultNamespace + "root",
       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
       new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", 
                      "http://www.foo.bar someSchema.xsd")
   )
);
```

I haven't really used the new XML features of C#, but it looks like you need to declare the `xsi` namespace properly.

See: http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/01/28/adding-schemalocation-attribute-to-xelement-in-linq-to-sql/ for more info.

Comment: Tanks, your link was great! The problem was on declaration in xsi namespace.